# MySQL INSERT INTO ... SELECT with subquery condition

Tags: mysql, subquery

I need to export all the records with a duplicate value in a field to a different table. Namely all records where `code` appears more than once must be copied.

This is the query I tried:

```
INSERT INTO alternatives
SELECT * FROM winter WHERE code IN 
    (SELECT code
     FROM winter
     GROUP BY code
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

but nothing happens, the mysql client hangs indefinitely until I stop it, and no records appear in the `alternatives` table. What am I doing wrong?

Alternatively, is there a better way to do what I need?

Comment: That is not the proper MySQL syntax for an INSERT - you need to specify VALUES. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Comment: That's not the problem, the INSERT is fine (it works without the IN condition), the SELECT with the subquery doesn't work even without the initial INSERT

Comment: can you tell me for what purpose you have put " HAVING COUNT(*) > 1"  ?

Comment: I need to export the duplicate records, so I group by code and look for those where that code appears more than once

Comment: There is no problem in your query unless `alternatives` and `winter` has different table structure. wait, you said it's work without `IN` condition?

Comment: Yes it works without the IN condition, it does a complete replica of the original table. Actually it's the SELECT with the subquery that doesn't work, if I remove the `INSERT INTO alternatives` it hangs

Comment: How many rows in table `winter`?

Comment: Around 100k, the results of the subquery (i.e. the number of duplicate codes) are 1420

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your query should work. I don't know, but you can try `INNER JOIN` instead `IN` clause. something like :

```
-- INSERT INTO alternatives
SELECT * FROM winter
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT code
     FROM winter
     GROUP BY code
     HAVING COUNT(code) > 1) DUP ON winter.code = DUP.code
```

First, try it without `INSERT` statement. If works, you know what to do.

Comment: This version with the JOIN works, still curious about why the one with the subquery doesn't